# Links don't work in Materialize tabs

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm relatively new to web development, and I'm using Materialize for the project I'm working on right now. My navbar code is attached, for some reason I can click on and follow the links in the sidebar, but not in the `nav-content` tabs. When I take out the `tabs tabs-transparent` classes in the `ul`, it works, but it looks ugly. I am loading JQuery- that was the only resolution I saw to this problem when I googled.

```html
<nav class="blue-grey lighten-1 nav-extended" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo center"><img src="/application/static/application/colorondarknotext.png" height=60px/></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Welcome, (USERNAME)!<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
      <li class="no-padding">
        <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
          <li>
            <a class="collapsible-header">Welcome, (USERNAME)!<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="/profile">Account Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="/accounts/logout">Log Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="divider"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/apply">Application</a></li>
      <li><a href="/decision">Decisions</a></li>
      <li><a href="/travel">Travel Information</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-content hide-on-med-and-down">
    <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
      <li class="tab"><a href="/apply">Application</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="/decision">Decisions</a></li>
      <li class="tab"><a href="/travel">Travel Information</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add your CSS code. My guess is there an element that is hidden which is covering your side bar.

Comment: My CSS and JS are both just the stock Materialize stuff, nothing in in my style.css, and just the button-collapse sidenav stuff in my init.js

Comment: If you are using a vanilla install I would suggest trying to start over with it working to see what step made it stop working. Based on the code you provided its hard to say. Do you see any errors in your console?

Answer (score 5):

I've run into a series of issues like this.

Generally you need to look deeper in the docs.  In this case the navbar component docs don't address the issue in their example code.  You need to look under javascript>tabs section of the docs to uncover more details about how the tabs work.

http://materializecss.com/tabs.html#external

> By default, Materialize tabs will ignore their default anchor behaviour. To force a tab to behave as a regular hyperlink, just specify the target property of that link!

The normal anchor (`<a>`) functionality is disabled/ignored.  In order to make your links work like "normal" you need to add a `target` attribute to your links.

Assuming you want to open the links in the same window, you would add `target="_self"` to each `<a>` tag.

```html
<li class="tab"><a href="/apply" target="_self">Application</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="/decision" target="_self">Decisions</a></li>
<li class="tab"><a href="/travel" target="_self">Travel Information</a></li>
```

Comment: thank you so much, was getting crazy on this. they should make it more evident